# Can't SSH to AirOS

Tags: linux, ssh

I get wireless Internet connection with device called "air OS". I can access it through the webpage, and from there enabled SSH access.

However, trying to SSH in is not working (using this command):

> ssh [ip-address]

It wants the root password from me which I have never defined, and I can't get any help in the company website.  I am stuck here and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the same password you use for the web configuration?

Comment: Yes ,it didn't works.

Comment: your talking about the UBNT air OS correct?

Comment: the default ubnt password / user is ubnt / ubnt

Comment: so now this question is un-answered again????

Answer (score 3):

You couldn't access root account , it can be access only by manufacture company and best way to access it is :

> [user@]hostname [command]

Comment: No, with the UBNT air OS you are the root user. We use hundreds of these for both repeaters and routers.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you didnt specify a username, you have to run your ssh command like this:

```
ssh (your router username)@(your router ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

The device is a wireless access point manufactured by Ubiquiti networks. The 'root' account does not exist; the only user account on these devices by default is "ubnt" (which has UID 0, so it's root for all intents and purposes).

You should be able to do everything you need to this through the web UI - why do you need SSH access? You said "I can't get any help in the company website", but the AirOS Users Guide is quite clear on this...